# Can a copper(II) chloride be added to liquified butane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What would happen to either chemical if the two were mixed together, specifically what would happen if the dust was mixed in when the Butane was in an aqueous state.

I have a limited knowledge of chemistry so I apologize if my terms are incorrect.

Comment: Copper chloride will just drop to the bottom and remain there.

Comment: "Butane in an aqueous state".  This has got to be good.

Answer (score 1):

If we had butane under pressure in a vessel as liquid and this was to be in contact with a solution of copper chloride in water then I think that nothing will happen. The butane and the water will form two seporate layers.

However if we were to add a copper extraction agent to the butane such as LIX-860 (a phenolic oxime reagent) then it would be possible to convert some of the copper from aqueous copper chloride into an organic soluble copper complex. Then the copper would be extracted into the butane layer.

Aother option would be to add copper chloride powder to the butane solution of LIX-860, I think that this could react but the reaction would be slower. Also I think that the hydrogen chloride formed as side product from the reaction would have a greater inhibiting effect on the reaction.

Another option would be to use a lipophilic chloride ionic liquid such as aliquat 336 to dissolve the copper chloride. This could react (slowly) with powdered copper(II) chloride to form 2(R4N+).[CuCl4]2- which would have some solubility in liquid butane. From my own experience of doing solvent extraction I know that aliquat 336 in alkanes is not a great system. When the metal loading becomes moderate the organic phase can separate into the organic solvent (diluent) and a liquid metal bearing layer.

In short I hold the view that pure butane will not be able to dissolve copper chloride, but with a suitable additive it will be possible to get a solution of copper in butane. The copper will be there as a copper complex.

I think that if we were to place water in a sealed container and put pure butane gas in the head space that the concentration of the butane in the aqueous layer will be very low. The copper chloride is likely to stay in the aqueous layer as hydrated copper ions and chloride anions if the concentration is low. If the concentration is high then it will be able to form chlorocomplexes of copper.

Comment: phenanthroline is a good reagent for complexing Copper salts and getting them into the organic phase.